# How to obtain Json data from different site

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

So, let's say i have **/api/cat/fact.js** directory.
I wanna to get JSON Data from [catfact.ninja](https://catfact.ninja/fact)

The thing is, i can't use **require()** or **request()** package, because if i used **require**, it would saya ****Couldnt Found Module...****, and if i used **request** one, instead of returning the JSON Data that you beable to sees in [catfact.ninja](https://catfact.ninja/fact), it return JSON about the api, like **hostname**, **port**, which is i don't need

**/API/api/cat/fact.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express.Router();
const request = require('request')

app.use('', (req, res) => {
const src = 'https://catfact.ninja/fact';
  const facts = request({
        uri: src,
        hostname: 'catfact.ninja',
        port: 443, 
    path: '/fact',
    method: 'POST',
        json: 'fact'
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if (error) console.log(error)
    console.log(body, '\n\n' + response.fact)
    })
        console.log(facts);
        return res.jsonp(facts)
})

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: hlep meh piliss

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: Wait, lemme get it

Comment: There
You got it

Comment: What's being outputted?

Comment: {"uri":{"protocol":"https:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"catfact.ninja","port":443,"hostname":"catfact.ninja","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/fact","path":"/fact","href":"https://catfact.ninja/fact"},"method":"POST","headers":{"host":"catfact.ninja","accept":"application/json","content-type":"application/json","content-length":6}}

Comment: I want the reply become something like {"fact": "FACT ABOUT CAT"}

Comment: No response?....

Comment: I've no idea where's this output is coming from. Maybe it's an error? `if (error) console.log(error)`

Comment: Its already like that before i added it..

Comment: This line `console.log(body)` should work, but make sure you know where the log is coming from

Comment: that one? Return `{  message: "" }` in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning JSON in the wrong place. It should be returned inside of the callback function.

Here's the solution:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request-promise')

const app = express();

app.use('', async (req, res) => {
  const src = 'https://catfact.ninja/fact';

  try {
    const response = await request({
      uri: src,
      port: 443, 
      method: 'GET',
      json: true
    })

    return res.jsonp(response)
  } catch (err) {
    return res.jsonp(err)
  }
})

function startServer() {
  const port = 3000

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.info('Server is up on port ' + port)
  })

  app.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  })
}
startServer()
```

**TIP:** I suggest using `request-promise` npm package instead of `request` package as it provides async-await approach, which is cleaner. Else, you can continue using callback function as second `request()` function parameter.

Comment: Thanks there! But i won't use the startServer() Function, because i already have 1 on my` index.js`

Comment: Hello there, just asking, why does i got the same thing? You can view [My APi Site](https://api.devs-api.repl.co/api/cat/fact) to see it.

Comment: Put `options` parameter as I did and it should be ok. If you are using async-await approach, `response` object from my solution gives you body, else if you use the callback function from `request` package, body is contained in your `body` parameter and you should return JSON inside of that callback function, and **not** after `request()` function.

Comment: Ah yeah, i forgot to change the package from `request` to `request-promise` .w.

Comment: Just remember to mark answer so others know it helped you.